# Laravel admin controller

Tags: laravel, sqlyog, laravel-admin

```php
$router->get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
$router->resource('users', UserController::class); //user auth
```

This is the command in laravel 7 to generate new controller which articles except for user but I got some issues where the error said the Model does not exist!

```
php artisan admin:make ArticlesController --model=App\Articles
```

above the command that I used

Comment: Where are you running the command? Did you try using double backslash? `php artisan admin:make ArticlesController --model=App\\Articles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If model `Articles` exist, you can use

```
php artisan admin:make ArticlesController --model=Articles
```

By default, models are created in the `App` directory in Laravel 7.

---

If you use `App\Articles` Laravel assume your model name as `AppArticles`.  [image]

if you need to create in the custom path, then use double `\\` like this

[image]

Comment: i forgot to create my model thats y . thanks anyways